# How to show "Published on"-date instead of "Last edited"-date in wordpress post's

Tags: wordpress, date, blogs

I have a theme for a blog in which im trying to modify, so that it always shows the "published date" instead for "Edited on" every time I edit it...

I have nailed it down to the file -> functions.php where it displays the dates... Section "Posted On Function"

But everytime i try to modify the if/else i get a error 500 on the page :-(

Some help would be highly appreciated here...

Thanks in advance!

-Best regards

Part that I suspect is the reason :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Posted On Function
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_posted_on() {

    if ( get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() ) {
        printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Last Updated:</span> %2$s', 'organic-swell' ),
            'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_modified_time() ),
                get_the_modified_date()
            )
        );
    } else {
        printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted:</span> %2$s', 'organic-swell' ),
            'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                get_the_date()
            )
        );
    }

}

/*
```

This is the entire functions.php file :

```
/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Theme Setup
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'swell_setup' ) ) :

    function swell_setup() {

        // Make theme available for translation.
        load_theme_textdomain( 'organic-swell', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        // Enable support for Post Thumbnails.
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // Enable support for site title tag.
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        add_image_size( 'swell-featured-large', 1800, 1200, true ); // Large Featured Image.
        add_image_size( 'swell-featured-medium', 1200, 800, true ); // Medium Featured Image.
        add_image_size( 'swell-featured-small', 640, 640, true ); // Small Featured Image.

        // Post Formats.
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
            'gallery',
            'link',
            'image',
            'audio',
            'status',
            'quote',
            'video',
            )
        );

        // Create Menus.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'fixed-menu' => esc_html__( 'Fixed Menu', 'organic-swell' ),
            'main-menu' => esc_html__( 'Main Menu', 'organic-swell' ),
            'social-menu' => esc_html__( 'Social Menu', 'organic-swell' ),
        ));

        // Custom Header.
        register_default_headers( array(
            'default' => array(
            'url'   => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-header.jpg',
            'thumbnail_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-header.jpg',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Default Custom Header', 'organic-swell' ),
            ),
        ));
        $defaults = array(
            'width'                 => 1800,
            'height'                => 480,
            'flex-height'           => true,
            'flex-width'            => true,
            'default-text-color'    => 'ffffff',
            'default-image'         => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-header.jpg',
            'header-text'           => false,
            'uploads'               => true,
        );
        add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );

        // Custom Background.
        $defaults = array(
            'default-color'          => 'eeeeee',
        );
        add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
    }
endif; // swell_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'swell_setup' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Theme Updater
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_theme_updater() {
    require( get_template_directory() . '/updater/theme-updater.php' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'swell_theme_updater' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Category ID to Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_cat_id_to_name( $id ) {
    $cat = get_category( $id );
    if ( is_wp_error( $cat ) ) {
        return false; }
    return $cat->cat_name;
}

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Register Scripts
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'swell_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
    function swell_enqueue_scripts() {

        // Enqueue Styles.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'swell-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'swell-style-mobile', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style-mobile.css', array( 'swell-style' ), '1.0' );

        // Resgister Scripts.
        wp_register_script( 'swell-fitvids', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fitvids.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20130729' );
        wp_register_script( 'swell-hover', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hoverIntent.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20130729' );
        wp_register_script( 'swell-superfish', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js', array( 'jquery', 'swell-hover' ), '20130729' );

        // Enqueue Scripts.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'swell-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.custom.js', array( 'jquery', 'swell-superfish', 'swell-fitvids', 'masonry' ), '20130729', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'swell-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20130729', true );

        // Load Flexslider on front page and slideshow page template.
        if ( is_home() || is_front_page() || is_single() || is_page_template( 'template-slideshow.php' ) || is_page_template( 'template-featured-content.php' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'swell-flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20130729' );
        }

        // Load single scripts only on single pages.
        if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'swell_enqueue_scripts' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Register Sidebars
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Default Sidebar', 'organic-swell' ),
        'id' => 'default-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Blog Sidebar', 'organic-swell' ),
        'id' => 'blog-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Left Sidebar', 'organic-swell' ),
        'id' => 'left-sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Footer Widgets', 'organic-swell' ),
        'id' => 'footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="footer-widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'swell_widgets_init' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Add Stylesheet To Visual Editor
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'swell_add_editor_styles' );
/**
 * Apply theme's stylesheet to the visual editor.
 *
 * @uses add_editor_style() Links a stylesheet to visual editor
 * @uses get_stylesheet_uri() Returns URI of theme stylesheet
 */
function swell_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'css/style-editor.css' );
}

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Posted On Function
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_posted_on() {

    if ( get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() ) {
        printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Last Updated:</span> %2$s', 'organic-swell' ),
            'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_modified_time() ),
                get_the_modified_date()
            )
        );
    } else {
        printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted:</span> %2$s', 'organic-swell' ),
            'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                get_the_date()
            )
        );
    }

}

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Post Format Meta Boxes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

add_action( 'admin_init', 'create_metaboxes' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metaboxes' );

$metaboxes = array(
    'link_url' => array(
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Link Information', 'organic-swell' ),
        'applicableto' => 'post',
        'location' => 'side',
        'display_condition' => 'post-format-link',
        'priority' => 'default',
        'fields' => array(
            'l_url' => array(
                'title' => esc_html__( 'Link URL: ', 'organic-swell' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'description' => '',
                'size' => 20,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'quote_author' => array(
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Quote Author', 'organic-swell' ),
        'applicableto' => 'post',
        'location' => 'side',
        'display_condition' => 'post-format-quote',
        'priority' => 'default',
        'fields' => array(
            'q_author' => array(
                'title' => esc_html__( 'Author: ', 'organic-swell' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'description' => '',
                'size' => 20,
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

function create_metaboxes() {
    global $metaboxes;

    if ( ! empty( $metaboxes ) ) {
        foreach ( $metaboxes as $id => $metabox ) {
            add_meta_box( $id, $metabox['title'], 'show_metaboxes', $metabox['applicableto'], $metabox['location'], $metabox['priority'], $id );
        }
    }
}

function show_metaboxes( $post, $args ) {
    global $metaboxes;

    $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $fields = $tabs = $metaboxes[ $args['id'] ]['fields'];

    /** Nonce */
    $output = '<input type="hidden" name="post_format_meta_box_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce( basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '" />';

    if ( sizeof( $fields ) ) {
        foreach ( $fields as $id => $field ) {
            switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                default:
                case 'text':

                    if ( isset( $custom[ $id ] ) ) {

                        $output .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '">' . $field['title']  . '</label><input id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" type="text" name="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" value="' . $custom[ $id ][0] . '" size="' . $field['size'] . '" />';

                    } else {

                        $output .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '">' . $field['title']  . '</label><input id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" type="text" name="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" value="" size="' . $field['size'] . '" />';

                    }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    echo $output;
}

function save_metaboxes( $post_id ) {
    global $metaboxes;

    // Verify nonce.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_format_meta_box_nonce'] ) && ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_format_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return $post_id; }

    // Check autosave.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id; }

    // Check permissions.
    if ( 'page' == isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id; }
    } elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $post_type = get_post_type();

    // Loop through fields and save the data.
    foreach ( $metaboxes as $id => $metabox ) {
        // Check if metabox is applicable for current post type.
        if ( $metabox['applicableto'] == $post_type ) {
            $fields = $metaboxes[ $id ]['fields'];

            foreach ( $fields as $id => $field ) {
                $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, $id, true );
                $new = $_POST[ $id ];

                if ( $new && $new != $old ) {
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, $id, $new );
                } elseif ( '' == $new && $old || ! isset( $_POST[ $id ] ) ) {
                    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $id, $old );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'display_metaboxes', 1000 );

function display_metaboxes() {
    global $metaboxes;
    if ( get_post_type() == 'post' ) :
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
            $ = jQuery;

            <?php
            $formats = $ids = array();
            foreach ( $metaboxes as $id => $metabox ) {
                array_push( $formats, "'" . $metabox['display_condition'] . "': '" . $id . "'" );
                array_push( $ids, '#' . $id );
            }
            ?>

            var formats = { <?php echo implode( ',', $formats );?> };
            var ids = "<?php echo implode( ',', $ids ); ?>";

            function displayMetaboxes() {
                // Hide all post format metaboxes.
                $(ids).hide();
                // Get current post format.
                var selectedElt = $("input[name='post_format']:checked").attr("id");

                // If exists, fade in current post format metabox.
                if ( formats[selectedElt] )
                    $("#" + formats[selectedElt]).fadeIn();
            }

            $(function() {
                // Show/hide metaboxes on page load
                displayMetaboxes();

                // Show/hide metaboxes on change event
                $("input[name='post_format']").change(function() {
                    displayMetaboxes();
                });
            });

            // ]]></script>
            <?php
    endif;
}

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Content Width
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 640; }

/**
 * Adjust content_width value based on the presence of widgets
 */
function swell_content_width() {
    if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'post-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'page-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'blog-sidebar' ) ) {
        global $content_width;
        $content_width = 960;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'swell_content_width' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comments Function
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'swell_comment' ) ) :
    function swell_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
        switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
            case 'pingback' :
            case 'trackback' :
        ?>
        <li class="post pingback">
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Pingback:', 'organic-swell' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( esc_html__( 'Edit', 'organic-swell' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
        break;
            default :
        ?>
        <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="<?php echo esc_attr( 'li-comment-' . get_comment_ID() ); ?>">

        <article id="<?php echo esc_attr( 'comment-' . get_comment_ID() ); ?>" class="comment">
            <footer class="comment-meta">
                <div class="comment-author vcard">
                    <?php
                        $avatar_size = 72;
                    if ( '0' != $comment->comment_parent ) {
                        $avatar_size = 48; }

                        echo get_avatar( $comment, $avatar_size );

                        /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: date and time */
                        printf( __( '%1$s <br/> %2$s <br/>', 'organic-swell' ),
                            sprintf( '<span class="fn">%s</span>', wp_kses_post( get_comment_author_link() ) ),
                            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"><time pubdate datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                                esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                                get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                                /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                                sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'organic-swell' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                            )
                        );
                        ?>
                    </div><!-- .comment-author .vcard -->
                </footer>

                <div class="comment-content">
                    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
                    <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'organic-swell' ); ?></em>
                    <br />
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php comment_text(); ?>
                    <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => esc_html__( 'Reply', 'organic-swell' ), 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .reply -->
                    <?php edit_comment_link( esc_html__( 'Edit', 'organic-swell' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div>

            </article><!-- #comment-## -->

        <?php
        break;
        endswitch;
    }
endif; // Ends check for swell_comment().

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disable Comments On Pages Default
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_default_comments_off( $data ) {
    if ( $data['post_type'] == 'page' && $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' ) {
        $data['comment_status'] = 0;
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'swell_default_comments_off' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Custom Excerpt Length
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 38;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'swell_excerpt_length', 999 );

function swell_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '... <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">'. esc_html__( 'Read More', 'organic-swell' ) .'</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'swell_excerpt_more' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Add Excerpt To Pages
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'swell_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function swell_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Custom Page Links
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add( $args ) {
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if ( ! $args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number' ) {
        return $args; }

    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; // Keep numbering for the main part
    if ( ! $more ) {
        return $args; }

    if ( $page -1 ) { // There is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page( $page -1 )
            . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'; }

    if ( $page < $numpages ) { // There is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page( $page + 1 )
            . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
            . $args['after']; }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_args', 'swell_wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Featured Video Meta Box
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

add_action( 'admin_init', 'admin_init_featurevid' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_featurevid' );

function admin_init_featurevid() {
    add_meta_box( 'featurevid-meta', esc_html__( 'Featured Video Embed Code', 'organic-swell' ), 'meta_options_featurevid', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function meta_options_featurevid() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $featurevid = isset( $custom['featurevid'] ) ? esc_attr( $custom['featurevid'][0] ) : '';

    echo '<textarea name="featurevid" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97.6%" />'.$featurevid.'</textarea>';
}

function save_featurevid( $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['featurevid'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featurevid', $_POST['featurevid'] );
    }
}

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Remove First Gallery
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_remove_gallery( $content ) {

    if ( is_page_template( 'template-slideshow.php' ) || has_post_format( 'gallery' ) || ( is_singular( 'jetpack-portfolio' ) && get_theme_mod( 'display_project_slideshow', false ) ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace( '/\[gallery(.*?)ids=[^\]]+\]/', '', $content, 1 );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'swell_remove_gallery' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Home Link In Custom Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function home_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'home_page_menu_args' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Body Class
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

function swell_body_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $classes[] = 'swell-singular'; }

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'swell-right-sidebar'; }

    if ( '' != get_theme_mod( 'background_image' ) ) {
        // This class will render when a background image is set
        // regardless of whether the user has set a color as well.
        $classes[] = 'swell-background-image';
    } else if ( ! in_array( get_background_color(), array( '', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-color' ) ) ) ) {
        // This class will render when a background color is set
        // but no image is set. In the case the content text will
        // Adjust relative to the background color.
        $classes[] = 'swell-relative-text';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_action( 'body_class', 'swell_body_class' );

/*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Includes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/jetpack.php' );
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/customizer.php' );
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/typefaces.php' );
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/woocommerce-setup.php' );
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/plugin-activation.php' );
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/plugin-activation-class.php' );
```

Comment: That's a big file you just shared...most of which has nothing to do with what you're trying to do. I'd first narrow your question down to the relevant code.

Comment: Hi mevius :-) I will try and narrow it down for you... Hoping that I doesn't leave any important out?!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
if ( get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() ) {
```

to

```
if ( get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() && false ) {
```